# My App crashes with no errors during build project Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I was trying to make an app to capture an image and store it in the file. There is no error while building the project but the app does not run on the AVD Pixel 2 API 24

This is the code for **MainActivity.java** :

```java
    package com.example.myapplication;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
    import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Locale;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    Button button;
    File photoFile = null;
    static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;


    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "MyApp";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView =  findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button = findViewById(R.id.btnCaptureImage);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    captureImage();
                }
                else
                {
                    captureImage2();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /* Capture Image function for 4.4.4 and lower. Not tested for Android Version 3 and 2 */
    private void captureImage2() {

        try {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            photoFile = createImageFile4();
            if(photoFile!=null)
            {
                displayMessage(getBaseContext(),photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
                Log.i("MyApp",photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
                Uri photoURI  = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            displayMessage(getBaseContext(),"Camera is not available."+e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void captureImage()
    {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                try {

                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    displayMessage(getBaseContext(),photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    Log.i("MyApp",photoFile.getAbsolutePath());

                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                "com.example.MyApplication.MainActivity",
                                photoFile);
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    displayMessage(getBaseContext(), ex.getMessage());
                }


            }else
            {
                displayMessage(getBaseContext(),"Null");
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        //Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        //Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        } else {
            displayMessage(getBaseContext(), "Request cancelled or something went wrong.");
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile4()
    {
        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                displayMessage(getBaseContext(),"Unable to create directory.");
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

        return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private void displayMessage(Context context, String message)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                captureImage();
            }
        }

    }
```

and this is the code for **AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.params.Face" />

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup">

        <provider
            android:name="android.content.SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
            </meta-data>
        </provider>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

but the logcat errors show

```
    2020-04-25 21:45:03.945 4722-4724/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xa8 in 
     tid 4724 (Binder:4722_2)

    --------- beginning of system
    2020-04-25 21:45:06.581 4726-4726/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    2020-04-25 21:45:06.581 4726-4726/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
    2020-04-25 21:45:06.583 4716-4716/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    2020-04-25 21:45:06.583 4716-4716/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
    2020-04-25 21:45:07.949 4746-4746/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    2020-04-25 21:45:07.949 4746-4746/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
    2020-04-25 21:45:08.585 4755-4755/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 4755
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.content.SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider: 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provider not configured
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5814)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5403)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5342)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provider not configured
        at 
     android.content.SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider.onCreate(SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider.java:305)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5811)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5403) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5342) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
       2020-04-25 21:45:09.728 1318-1318/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1318: eglCreateSyncKHR(1901): error 0x3004 
    (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
```

It would be really helpful if I would be helped in finding a solution to this problem.

Comment: have u tried restarting avd . If so , try manual command using adb to install and check it works or not ?

Comment: i am still unable to run it. is there any other way?

Comment: Have you configured project paths under res/XML?

Comment: the only file under res\XML is file_paths.xml i am not sure as to what you mean as i am kinda new to android studio app development

Comment: As [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider) says, you're supposed to create your own class that extends `SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider`. Also, you have a typo in your call to `getUriForFile`; you've put `"MyApplication"` in the authority string, but it should be `"myapplication"`.

Comment: initially it was 
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" i had changed it to android:name="android.content.SearchRecentSuggestionsProvider" as the previous line was showing errors.